# How to plot missing dates in time series data using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, missing-data

I have a time series data of Temperature (average, maximum, minimum) with missing dates, and the line plot is not continue, this graph does a jump with a horizontal line until the next date. I would like that the line be continue.

My data set is the next

```r
Fecha      -- T      Tmin Tmax

1. Fecha      ---------- T   --   Tmin Tmax
2. 2015-07-01   - 11,16 - 7,3 -  17 
3. 2015-07-02    - 11,49 -   8   - 17,1
4. 2015-07-03   - 11,2 -    8,8 -     15,8
5. 2015-07-04 - 11,20 - 8,6  - 16
6. 2015-07-05    -11,23 -   8,9  - 15,7
7. 2015-07-06    -10,40  - 7,7  -  15,4
8. 2015-07-07 - 10,10 - 8,1 -  14,8
9. 2015-07-08 - 10,04 - 7,3 -  15,4
10. 2018-01-01   - 11,08 -  4,9 -  17,8
11. 2018-01-02   -11,40 -   4,2 -  16,3
12. 2018-01-03 -    9,000 - 5,5  - 13,5
13. 2018-01-04  - 8,584  - 6    -  12,8
14. 2018-01-05  - 8,679  - 7,3  -  11,9
15. 2018-01-06 -    8,75 -  6,8 -  13
16. 2018-01-07   - 9,33 - 6,4    - 15,2
17. 2018-01-08  - 9,63 -    6,3 -  13,9
```

My code is:

```r
setwd("C:/Users/2018/Documents/Belmira")
dir()
mmp1<-read.csv2("Temperatura.csv")
head(mmp1)
p<-as.Date(mmp1$Fecha)
mmp1$Fecha<-p
w<-ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mmp1$Fecha, y = mmp1$Tmin, colour="Min"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mmp1$Fecha, y = mmp1$T, colour="P"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mmp1$Fecha, y = mmp1$Tmax, colour="Max"), size=0.71) +
  ylim(c(1,18))+
  theme (text = element_text(size=11)) +
  ylab(expression("Temperatura (°C)"))+
  xlab(expression("Tiempo"))+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "30 day", date_labels = "%m-%y", limits = as.Date(c('2015-07-01','2019-01-01')), expand = (c(0.001,0.008)))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white', size = 1.2, linetype = 7))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="arial", face="bold", size=12))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", family = "arial", vjust=1.5, colour="black", hjust = 0.5, size=rel(1.2)))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", family = "arial", vjust=0.5, colour="black", size=rel(1.2)))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family= "arial",face = "plain", colour="black", size=rel(1.1)))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family= "arial",face = "plain", colour="black", size=rel(1.1)))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, 28, 2), limits = c(-4,28), expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Leyenda",
                      values=c(Min="green", P="#56B4E9", Max="Red"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold", family = "arial"))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(order = 2),
         shape=guide_legend(order = 2))
w
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. Please see @stefan 's answer in order to see how to post data. Best is to use an inbuilt data set though. there are plenty in R, for time series there is for example `AirPassengers`

Comment: also have a look at my comment to Stefan's answer - this was mainly posted for you to learn! Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right you want the gaps in your data not show up as "a long horizontal" line? This is no simple task. Perhaps the prefered and simplest solution would be to use facetting, e.g. by year. If you insist on having all the data in one plot then you have to try a hacky approach, by getting rid of the date-axis and setting the labels manually. Have a look at the different approaches:

```r
df <- read.table(text="
    Fecha - T - Tmin - Tmax
    2015-07-01 - 11,16 - 7,3 - 17
    2015-07-02 - 11,49 - 8 - 17,1
    2015-07-03 - 11,2 - 8,8 - 15,8
    2015-07-04 - 11,20 - 8,6 - 16
    2015-07-05 - 11,23 - 8,9 - 15,7
    2015-07-06 - 10,40 - 7,7 - 15,4
    2015-07-07 - 10,10 - 8,1 - 14,8
    2015-07-08 - 10,04 - 7,3 - 15,4
    2018-01-01 - 11,08 - 4,9 - 17,8
    2018-01-02 - 11,40 - 4,2 - 16,3
    2018-01-03 - 9,000 - 5,5 - 13,5
    2018-01-04 - 8,584 - 6 - 12,8
    2018-01-05 - 8,679 - 7,3 - 11,9
    2018-01-06 - 8,75 - 6,8 - 13
    2018-01-07 - 9,33 - 6,4 - 15,2
    2018-01-08 - 9,63 - 6,3 - 13,9
", header = TRUE, dec = ",")

mmp1 <- df[,!grepl("^X", names(df))]
mmp1$Fecha <- as.Date(mmp1$Fecha)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mmp2 <- mmp1 %>% 
  mutate(
    year_fecha = as.character(lubridate::year(Fecha)),
    Fecha2 = format(Fecha, "%d-%m"),
    Fecha2 = forcats::fct_reorder(Fecha2, Fecha)) %>% 
  arrange(Fecha) %>% 
  rowid_to_column(var = "Fecha3")

# Put the theme code aside
polish <- theme(text = element_text(size=11)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white', size = 1.2, linetype = 7))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="arial", face="bold", size=12))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", family = "arial", vjust=1.5, colour="black", hjust = 0.5, size=rel(1.2)))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", family = "arial", vjust=0.5, colour="black", size=rel(1.2)))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family= "sans",face = "plain", colour="black", size=rel(1.1)))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family= "sans",face = "plain", colour="black", size=rel(1.1)))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold", family = "arial"))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))

# Simple and prefered solution: Facet by e.g. by year
w1 <- ggplot(data = mmp2) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha, y = Tmin, colour="Min"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha, y = T, colour="P"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha, y = Tmax, colour="Max"), size=0.71) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d-%m", expand = (c(0.001,0.008)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, 28, 2), limits = c(1,18), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Leyenda",
                      values=c(Min="green", P="#56B4E9", Max="Red")) +
  ylab("Temperatura (C)")+
  xlab("Tiempo") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(order = 2),
         shape=guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  facet_wrap(~year_fecha, scales = "free_x") +
  polish

w1
```

[image]

```r
# Hacky solutions with some manual labelling
labs <- select(mmp2, Fecha3, Fecha2) %>% 
  tibble::deframe()

date_lab <- function(x) {
  labs[as.character(x)]
}

# Draw the data as one continuous line
w2 <- ggplot(data = mmp2) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = Tmin, colour="Min"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = T, colour="P"), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = Tmax, colour="Max"), size=0.71) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.integer(names(labs)), labels = date_lab, expand = (c(0.001,0.008))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, 28, 2), limits = c(1,18), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Leyenda",
                      values=c(Min="green", P="#56B4E9", Max="Red")) +
  ylab("Temperatura (C)")+
  xlab("Tiempo") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(order = 2),
         shape=guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  polish
w2
```

[image]

```r
# Separate lines for years by using different linetypes 
w3 <- ggplot(data = mmp2) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = Tmin, colour="Min", linetype = year_fecha), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = T, colour="P", linetype = year_fecha), size=0.71) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Fecha3, y = Tmax, colour="Max", linetype = year_fecha), size=0.71) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.integer(names(labs)), labels = date_lab, expand = (c(0.001,0.008))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, 28, 2), limits = c(1,18), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Leyenda",
                      values=c(Min="green", P="#56B4E9", Max="Red")) +
  ylab("Temperatura (C)")+
  xlab("Tiempo") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(order = 2),
         shape=guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  polish
w3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: you probably know, but you can drastically improve your plot codes by calling theme only once and using long data and calling geom_line also only once, and passing linetype aesthetic

Comment: Yes I know. But in my opinion totally revising other users code is not necessarily the best way for them to learn and improve their R skills. So I try to stick as near to the original code as possible to focus on the solution of the main problem. (;

Comment: That's what I thought. I pointed the OP to my comment, because it was mostly for them... One little thing at a time, I guess..